# Preview update in Facebook wrong already fixed in original

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I write www.elecmeza.com I got the preview of my website with a cut picture and an orthographic error already fixed on the website... how long does it take to fb to update, I can't send the link with the error?

Comment: No need to SHOUT your titles...

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed as "not a real question". I had the same question, google searched, found this page, and discovered that the answer below was the answer I needed.

Answer (score 5):

The cache is updated every 24 hours, if you want to manually clear the cache you can use the URL debug tool at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug